# Java and SQL server first() function error

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc

I'm trying to get the first row in database using JDBC and go last but error message appear to me:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The result set has no current row.

My code is

```
String sql="select * from Machines";

try {
    stmt =  conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,  ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
    rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

    if(rs.first()) {
        jCombBrands.setSelectedItem(getN_brandNum(rs.getInt("BrandID")));
        txt_Ram.setText(rs.getString("Ram"));
        txt_poN.setText(rs.getString("PONummber"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `select * from Machines` returns any data? Have you verified this?

Comment: instead of rs.first, first check for hasNext()

while hasNext -> next

Comment: Which line of code did you get exception at?